# How to write jQuery to fix the asp.net Repeater with radio button list to select one value at time

Tags: jquery, repeater, radiobuttonlist

I want to select only one radio button but I cant do this. Here is my code:

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">

     <HeaderTemplate>
         <table class="tblcolor">
             <tr class="rowcolor">
             <b>
             </b>
             </tr>
</HeaderTemplate>

     <ItemTemplate>
<tr class="tblrowcolors">
<td><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.QuestionsText")%></td>


     <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">

   <asp:ListItem selected="true"> 1</asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem> 2</asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem> 3</asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem> 4</asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem> 5</asp:ListItem>


    </asp:RadioButtonList>

</tr>
</ItemTemplate>
```

I have investigate the problem and it says "it is bug in ASP.NET Repeater" and I have followed some articles and says need to fix by writing jquery !! Unfortunately I am beginner web developer I do not have a lot of experience with jQuery !! Any help please 
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Why you want to select only one radio button? can you clarify what you want to do exactly?

Comment: Imagine I have these options: oVeryGood oGood oBad  and I want to select just Good option for example !! that is why I need to select only one radio button at times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can’t fix this by changing the name value in the code-behind, it’s a bug/feature of ASP.NET.  Trust me, I’ve done the research and legwork on this one for you. Look
[this](http://www.ifinity.com.au/Blog/EntryId/87/Simple-fix-for-Radio-Button-controls-in-an-ASP-NET-Repeater-using-jQuery).